# Security with software accesing db?

Tags: .net, security

this can be asked with webform or winform...

i have a .net program (exe) which needs to access a db. ( via internet )

ofcourse this db requires password and login.

What is the best practice of accesing the db  which wont be seen with fiddler , reflector etc...?

i think the only solution is to use ssl + encrypting the connection string section and deCrypt it while runtime...

is there any better solution ?

Comment: If your RDBMS supports certificate-based authentication, that might be a good option.

Comment: @HackedByChinese the certificate will sit at the client side ?

Comment: The server should authenticate itself to the client as well.

Comment: @Gumbo 2 certificates on both sides ?

Comment: The best would be when both certificates are issued by the same CA. This could even be your own CA if only your own systems communicate with each other.

Comment: It's impossible to securely encrypt/decrypt the connection string on the client because where do you hide the key? Need a layer between client and db, such as a web service, that handles the security.

Comment: @dotjoe can you please supply an example ? (abstract one). i have an exe file at one side and a server in other side of the world.  youre saying that the exe file  / (also the hacker) can connect to the web service - in order to get data from db.... how my service will make sure the caller was my exe file and not the hacker ? a special calculated guid is fine. but in reverse engineering the hacker can see what is the algorithm to create again the guid... help please?

Comment: That is an authentication issue, it's been traditionally solved with username/password. The password would be known by the end user. You could never be 100% sure a user is who they authenticated as...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is a .exe that is being run by an attacker then he can use a debugger to obtain the username/password.  If this .exe is running on a machine you trust,  and the attacker **can only exist on the network** then SSL is perfect.

A Defense In Depth approach is that you shouldn't trust any part of your application unless you have to.  When an attacker hacks your application,  he is going to use your application's functionally against you.

How this should be done is create an API, such as a RESTful or SOAP API to access the datastore.  Vulnerabilities like SQL Injection will always be a serious concern,  but giving the attacker a raw database connection is even worse.

Comment: can he see the password which im being decrpyt at runtime ? ( exe file)

Comment: @Royi Namir  if your program can see it at run time, then a debugger can see it at run time.  You can never trust code running on a client.

Comment: ok so how will th software will connect to db ? what are those API ?  can you supply a link or something please ? also if the software connect through API  , so the hacker ALSO can do it.

Comment: @Royi Namir you have to build an api.  And yes,  the attacker will always have access to whatever remote interface you provide.  Welcome to the world of security.

Comment: if im  the service. how can i know the request came from my software and not from an attacker ?

Comment: @Royi Namir ssl and a password? (cryptographic nonce)

Comment: still where will i save the password in the client side ?